# Specify multiple senders in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm trying to specify multiple senders in my `didSelectItemAt` for my `UICollectionViewCell`. However when I specify more than one, then it returns a **found nil while unwrapping optional** error. For example

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailViewC", sender: monsters)
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailViewC", sender: abilities)
```

It reads the monster data in the second view controller just fine until I add the second sender `abilities`. Then it can't read the monster data at all but it can read the ability data. How can I specify them both so the next view controller reads both sent values?

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to imply what data is added to the segue, and you want both the monsters and the abilities sent. You called for the segue with the monsters first, so you need to have the abilities already attached to the data you want to pass in the segue.

You should have a struct for Monster that contains an optional property ability or abilities.

```
struct Monster {

    var abilities: [Ability]?

}
```

Prior to having the monsters: [Monster] array send the segue, assign the abilities to the proper monsters.

Comment: Ok, I've been reading and now understand how structs work but... where in my code does the struct actually go?

Comment: I usually give a struct it's own file or put it with some other data model related code if it logically fits there. It's just like a class declaration.

Answer (score -2):

Send a dictionary with both monsters and abilities as values for keys. 
A cleaner pattern would be to pass an actual sender (self) and use it as a delegate and read whatever you need through method calls.